# cakephp add new controller path

Tags: cakephp, path, controller, addition

**Background:** I'm new to `CakePHP` and trying to modify an preexisting project.
When I try to add a new `UploadsController` it is supposed to handle xxxx/uploads requests right?
However, when entering the `url` neither `AppController` or `UploadsController`, allow `index.php` to do a dispatch. Files are being called. It goes straight to /uploads which is a directory.

I realize this is a bad design to begin with but trying to fix things one step at a time. Need to authenticate before going to /uploads, and than take action.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to modify `routes.php` to specify controller but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

So as I said I am new and fixing someone else's project. I found that there is a security issue where uploads directory is exposed. So I figured I would add Controller to take care of this. uploads folder was under webroot as a result it was going to uploads folder and was not directing to controller. Thanks and hopes this helps someone in the future.. although kind of doubt it since it was a really bad way to do this to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

With the info you gave this is what I can suggest:

1. Check to see if the UploadsController is in the Controller folder.
2. Make sure that there's at least a index.ctp file in Views/Uploads/
3. Check to see if the UploadsController has a default index() method. This is what www.example.com/uploads/ will hit.

Comment: 1. was a yes
2. was a not - fixed
3. yes

Still does not work. I am not hitting top directory index.php either. Its like it is going outside the app all together.

Comment: Do you also have Upload.php in the Models/ folder? Sorry just trying to make sure all the small stuff is taken care of since you said you only created the controller. Please check CakePHP's blog tutorial for seeing how that's set up.

Comment: yes, that is there as well. Wouldn't this give me some other error though?
That's just it I think I have everything set up the same way other controllers are that are working.